# mingw cannot find my dependencies folder for GLFW

Tags: c++, g++, mingw, glfw

I'm trying to compile the code found in https://www.glfw.org/documentation. This code is in "main.cpp" and I have a folder in the same directory called "dependencies" containing: "glfw3.h", "glfw3.lib" and "libglfw3.a".
[project directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/05jYV.png)
[dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NLYSw.png)

I go to the directory in powershell and run:

```
g++ main.cpp -ldependencies .\dependencies\libglfw3.a -lopengl32 -lgdi32
```

and it returns:

```
c:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -ldependencies: No such file or directory
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What have I done wrong?

I've looked all the internet for solutions but none have worked even when I exactly do what is shown on the tutorial or solution, im quite stuck. I think its because im attempting to do this without an IDE (I used visual studio) and until recently i've only did C++ development with an IDE and i'm inexperienced with compiling and linking outside of IDE's.

Comment: I'd recommend installing GLFW from [MSYS2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30069830/how-can-i-install-mingw-w64-and-msys2) as a package, along with a compiler. This will make things slightly easier for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
g++ main.cpp -ldependencies .\dependencies\libglfw3.a -lopengl32 -lgdi32
```

should be

```
g++ main.cpp -Ldependencies -lglfw3 -lopengl32 -lgdi32
```

`-L` for a directory to search, `-l` for the name of the library to link with.